# How should I align two separated items of unequal widths?

Tags: alignment, applications

Recently, I've come across two cases where I have two items separated either by a vertical line `|` or a bullet `*`.

Here is one of the cases with an arrow pointing at the bullet:

[image: Example of question]

So my question is, how should this be aligned - should the bullet be aligned with the horizontal center of the view (so that one item stretches more to the side than the other one), or should the entire row be horizontally aligned (so that now the dividing bullet is off center)?

Comment: Maybe I'm overthinking the context but why did you separate the 2 navigation areas? What's behind the difference in priority and hierarchy?

Comment: Change "Website" to "Go to Website" and the text lengths are so close it won't matter which way you align it :)

Comment: @17of26 that's actually not a bad idea - grammatically, they're not equal right now, since one is an action phrase and the other's a noun.

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot is the best answer.

- **Emphasize structure**: About | Credits is horizontally **aligned by the |**
- **Emphasize content**: Report a Bug * Website is horizontally **aligned by entire row**

Answer (score 1):

The entire row should be horizontally aligned, as shown.  The overall look and feel is better that way.